# Can an employer pressure you into seeing their counsellor or psychologist ? And if so, if you refuse to go what can they do?

Tags: bullying

I have been experiencing workplace bullying and took the matter to management who referred the matter onto HR.  And now they are pressuring me to see their workplace psychologist.

Would also like to ask one further question in relation to this matter.  Thirdly, what is the nastiest thing they can do to you if you refuse to go?

Comment: Where are you located? Country and state/province.

Comment: So they are protecting the perpetrator and focusing on you. Are there any outside resources to contact? Workers tribunal etc

Comment: Not even your doctor can "make" you see a mental health professional. Unless maybe you present a danger to yourself and others. I would be very surprised if this wasn't the case anywhere.

Comment: @Peter seen it done to a colleague and very similar story...

Comment: @SolarMike: In Switzerland? This would certainly be very illegal in Germany.

Comment: @Peter oh depends how they "wrap" it...

Comment: It also depends on the job - there are quite some jobs where a psychologist may be able to pull you off duty or has to certify you for duty. There are other jobs where the employer can refuse your work for a lot of reasons, asking for a psych eval being one.

Comment: @Maggie, If you can afford it, go see your own psychologist, one that specializes in bullying, and one that works for you, not your employer.

Comment: *Not sure how to answer all the above questions because I am new to this platform.* @Maggie Generally you want to add any answers to requests for clarification to the question with an [edit]. Since all posts have an edit history, you don't need to put your changes under an "EDIT" header and can put changes wherever they make the most sense in your post. You can also '@' one person in a comment if you want to let them know you updated the question. (Answering in comments is fine but not ideal because the info usually also needs to be in the question.)

Comment: However, since your question is currently closed, if you can edit it so that it can be reopened you should do that first before making any clarifying edits (or do all the edits at once) since only the first edit puts your post into the Re-open queue. (You can also make a request on [meta] if you feel your post should be reopened.)

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to handle this. One is to refuse to go. Refusing is likely to result in negative job consequences. Another is to go and give misleading answers.

A third way is to go and treat the psychologist as a trained resource you can ask questions of. In other words, instead of seeing that person as an authority over you, see that person as a resource for *your* learning. The situation is workplace bullying. So, here is someone who may, repeat, *may* have some ideas that can help you in the situation. If you are paying for any sessions, then you are the boss and the psychologist is your employee. Treat the psychologist that way - someone you are hiring to give you ideas and encouragement to improve your situation.

A fourth way is to see this situation as totally toxic and get a new job as quickly as possible. If they are paying for the sessions, then they can get the information you say and what the psychologist thinks you are saying or hiding. If they are paying the psychologist, then getting out of there might be the best thing to do.

Comment: "If they are paying for the sessions, then they can get the information you say and what the psychologist thinks you are saying or hiding." I doubt any certified professional would risk his own career.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, But that's the thing, is that person even a licensed psychologist? For all they know, that person has a psychology degree and was hired to work as an HR rep. You do not know that person. You do not even have a contract with that person.  And yes, you can hire a psychologist that will side with you 90% of the time. This happens all the time in US court proceedings. This is the reason why the defense is usually also allowed to hire their own expert to contradict another expert hired by the other party.

Comment: You can actually report the psychologist to the governing board if they write a fraudulent report.

Comment: Not sure how to answer all the above questions because I am new to this platform.  I am in Australia, maybe can take them to the Fair Work Commission for a constructive dismissal, but I need to find a psychologist who would write me up a positive report, however that's hard for 2 reasons.  1) they want people coming back all the time so they can make money - I would walk away if they tried to manipulate me like that and 2) because they don't want to get dragged into legal battles because it would possibly damage their reputations if the other party was more cunning.

Comment: Peter you are right.  Tom Tom I suspect you are right, particularly if it is a job related to health.

Comment: I think they want to get a psychologist involved because I used the word "bullying" by my manager, so they want to discredit me. I actually did see their psychologist who was a fraudster (because my lawyer's abandoned me, refusing to give me any help when I most needed it) so I did end up reporting her to the board, because she made me do a personality test and as I wasn't finished she said not to worry.  One of the junior HR managers was on my side I think and I ended up seeing some of the report and this so called "professional" psychologist had suggested I return to her for counselling.

Comment: The lawyer actually didn't tell me not to go to the employers psychologist and occupational Dr.  Their occupational doctor is a fraudster too, I've worked out from seeing articles on the internet about him and 2 serious cases of breach of care (I suspect this is what it is termed).  The lawyer told me I had to see my own psychologist before she would help me further, which left me very vunerable because I was being pressured into seeing the employers psychologist the next day.  Here the board is very lenient re. bad doctors.

Comment: Yes, she was a psychologist I checked her name out on the board registration website.  I feel very silly for going now, and it has caused me real concerns.  I wish in hindsight I had taken them for constructive dismissal and defamation but it's very, very hard to find a good lawyer.

Comment: I should have written I needed a psychologist who would help write a positive report.  Pity I didn't have good help prior at the time.  Thank you for you honest answers.

Comment: I think (but I'm not a layer, a psychologist and I do not even work in HR) that you first need to understand WHY they asked you to see their psychologist. Is it to provide some sort of counselling because you have been bullied? That's good but you definitely can refuse to do it. Is it to asses your "emotional status" to corroborate or to discredit your claim? Consult a lawyer before doing anything else. Not sure in your country but it COULD be illegal to do so. What the psychologist's job is makes a huge difference here.